# Bug after app store deployment, unable to repro in Ad Hoc deployment

Tags: ios, debugging, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding, ad-hoc-distribution

My application is involves users saving data which I store using NSCoding/NSKeyedArchiver.  I supply the user with sample data objects on the first run of the app.

**The expected behavior happens during regular testing, as well as through ad hoc deployment. Unfortunately, a significant bug happens when the app is downloaded through the app store.**

What other environmental considerations might there be so I can reproduce (and then fix) the issue in my regular testing?

**Expected behavior:**

A new user may add/edit data objects in addition to the current ones. (A classic CRUD scenario).

**Actual behavior:**

If the user's first action is to *save* a new object, all of the previously loaded sample objects disappear (the elusive bug).
However, If the user's first action is to *edit*, then all of objects persist as expected, and the user can add additional ones without issue.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

In my most recent testing, I switched the *Build Configuration* to release in the "Run " scheme.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D01Ix.png

*App Delegate, which correctly initializes app*

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    self.dataArray = nil;
    self.dataArray = [AppDelegate getArray];
    if (self.dataArray == nil) {
        self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    //First run of the app
    if (dataArray.count == 0) {
        //Add sample data to array
        //Save array
        NSString *path = [AppDelegate getDocPath];
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.dataArray toFile:path];
    }
}

+(NSString *) getDocPath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempDocPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FilePath.dat"];
    return tempDocPath; 
}

+(NSMutableArray *)getArray {
    return [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[AppDelegate getDocPath]] mutableCopy];
}
```

*Object creation, which deletes preloaded data if data hasn't been edited*

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    tempArray = nil;
    tempArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[AppDelegate getDocPath]];
    if (tempArray == nil) {
        tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
    }   
}

-(void)saveObject {
    [tempArray addObject:createdData];
    [tempArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSString *path = [AppDelegate getDocPath];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:tempArray toFile:path];
    AppDelegate *dg = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    dg.dataArray = tempArray;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the add and edit tasks?  There's got to be some difference between the two in the way they interact with the filesystem.  For just one example, the add method might be creating a file with the same name as the directory with the sample files.

Comment: which environmental settings do u have? Debug, Release, ifdef's...

Comment: Added code as well as screenshot of some scheme settings. Any idea why they would preclude the bug from being reproduced?

Comment: are there any preprocessor macros that are changing the flow (or the target server) of your app on launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess while saving the new object, you are not appending it to the existing data. You might be over-writing the previously created file. You should access the previous file and append the new data to the previous file. Sharing code would help to point out where you are going wrong.

**EDIT:** Replace the following code and check if its still showing the same behaviour

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    tempArray = nil;
    tempArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[AppDelegate getDocPath]mutableCopy];
    if (tempArray == nil) {
        NSLog(@"tempArray is nil"); //if tempArray doesn't get initialized by the file contents  
        tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to solve your current problem (without looking at the code), but here's how you can avoid it in the future:

Make sure that the build you submit to the app store is the ad-hoc build you have QA'd, but signed with an app store provisioning profile.

Two advantages:
1) You should be able to repro the same bug on the adhoc and appstore build
2) dSym for both these are the same. So, you dont have to wait to get the AppStore crash logs before you can dig in and see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks calvinBhai.  Yes, in the organizer I AdHoc distributed same Archive that I originally submitted to the app store. Sadly, this did not make a difference.